# study the uniform convergence of this sereis of functions:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider the following series on the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x>0\}$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nx}$$

Does the series converge uniformly on $A$ or some subsets?

The idea is to obeserve that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nx}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^nx} \Big(3^nx\sin\frac{1}{3^nx}\Big)$$

If we were able to say that $\sin\frac{1}{3^nx}<\frac{1}{3^nx}$ for all $x$ then the exercise ends by Weiestrass criterion, but such inequality needs not hold for every $x\in A$. How do we proceed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges uniformly in every set of the form
$$
A=[a,\infty),
$$
where $a>0$.

**Proof.**
Using the fact that
$$
|\sin x|\le |x|, 
$$
we have that for $x>0$
$$
\left|\sin \frac{1}{x}\right|\le\frac{1}{x}
$$
So if $x\in [a,\infty)$, then we have
$$
\left|2^n\sin\frac{1}{3^nx}\right|\le\frac{2^n}{3^nx}\le \frac{2^n}{3^na},
$$
and $\sum \frac{2^n}{3^na}<\infty,$
and hence the series converges absolutely and uniformly in $[a,\infty)$.

On the other hand the series DOES NOT converge uniformly in $(0,\infty)$. To see this, consider
$$
x_n=\frac{2}{3^n\pi},
$$
and
$$
s_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k\sin\frac{1}{3^kx}.
$$
Then $s_n(x_n)-s_{n-1}(x_n)=2^n$, and hence the sequence $\{s_n(x)\}$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: I think you mean $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}$

Comment: @DavideTrono That's right! I corrected it.